# Save the login session on android WebView

Tags: php, android, session, webview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        websettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        String path = getApplicationContext().getDir("cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();

        websettings.setDatabasePath(path);

        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        websettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        websettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        websettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.requestFocus();
        //load webview
        webView.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomViewClient());
        hideNavigation();
    }
```

```
//load web view
private class CustomViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    //pagestart

    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        view.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void hideNavigation(){
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }
}
```